# Android offline mode (syncing data when app goes online)

Tags: java, android, api, data-synchronization, offline-mode

I want to gather data in online/offline mode, and when the internet connection is dropped data should be store in locally, and once the internet connection is back data should sync/push to the server.

**What library or technique recommended for achieve that?**

Answer (score 0):

Try to store data in offline using Room data base or Sqlite. after storing the data check internet connection continuously, if internet has connected upload that data to your server and drop local data.